# Possibility of a tree from a given degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory, trees

For each degree sequence below, decide whether it must always, must never, or could possibly be a degree sequence for a tree. Remember, a degree sequence lists out the degrees (number of edges incident to the vertex) of all the vertices in a graph in non-increasing order.

One of the given degree sequences was: (2,2,2,1,1). The answer to this was "possibly". I guess I may not be understanding the question correctly. This image is how I interpret the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8OMH.jpg

I do not see how it is possible to create a tree from the given degree sequence without having some branches without leafs on the tree.

Comment: You seem to be thinking about this from a computer science point of view with binary trees and such. In graph theory, a tree is just a connected graph with no cycles.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tree with this degree sequence:

```
1 --- 2 --- 2 --- 2 --- 1
```

Here is a graph that *isn't* a tree, with the same degree sequence:

```
1 --- 1    2 --- 2
            \   /
             \ /
              2
```

Therefore a graph with this degree sequence could be a tree, but isn't guaranteed to be a tree.

Comment: Following that, would the sequence: (3,3,3,1) then also be a possibility?

Comment: Well, to begin with, can you draw *any* graph with that degree sequence?

Comment: Right. In the problem I am solving for, the correct answer sequence: (3,3,3,1) is "never". https://imgur.com/a/IQVdbjT